# Moving to Neo4j 3.1.0 and IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath

Tags: maven, spring-boot, neo4j, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to move my project to Neo4j 3.1.0 but right now my Maven, Spring Boot application fails with a following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Neo4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/.../.m2/repository/org/neo4j/neo4j-security-enterprise/3.1.0/neo4j-security-enterprise-3.1.0.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.Neo4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
```

Could you please advise, what a logger implementation should be used in this case in my application and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following exclusion solve the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-enterprise</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-security-enterprise</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```